# Can I change the command bindings back to control bindings on Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been a Linux user for years and just got a Mac. One thing that has been bugging me for the past couple of days is how every program seems to use <kbd>command</kbd> for shortcuts instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Specifically in Firefox shortcuts, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, are switched to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Does anyone know of a way to switch these back? I know there is a way to switch the keys entirely, but I still need them to work correctly for my VMs.

Comment: Learn to live with it. You're not going to beat it. As someone who's used "all 3" [Mac, Win, nix] for 20+ years, there's really no better way than just "get used to it".

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10471/remapping-keys-to-match-windows

Comment: @pkamb I mentioned in the question that this would mess with my virtual machines sorry If I was unclear, I was more looking for a firefox specific fix, maybe a about:config change?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Karabiner to do this - bundle_indentifiers applies the change only to the selected app.

add a [complex modification](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/):

```
{
  "title": "apps",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Browsers",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "conditions": [ { "bundle_identifiers": ["^org\\.mozilla\\.firefox", "^com\\.microsoft\\.edgemac", "^com\\.apple\\.Safari"], "type": "frontmost_application_if" } ],
          "from": { "key_code": "left_control" },
          "to": [ { "key_code": "left_command" } ]
        }]
    }]
}
```